# All equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences can be represented by a series

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a normed complex vector space consisting of finite linear combinations of some countable set of vectors $v_n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I’d like to prove (if true!) that every element of the completion of V can be written (not necessarily uniquely) as a series
$$
S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n v_n
$$
for some coefficients $c_n\in\mathbb{C}$.

In other words: every equivalence class of Cauchy sequences contains a sequence $\{S_N\}$ of partial sums
$$
S_N = \sum_{n=0}^N c_n v_n
$$
for some $c_n$.

Comment: What values are the $c_n$ allowed to take? (rational, real, complex, integer, finite field...)

Comment: Complex is the main case I’m interested in; I’ve edited to clarify.